# iOS how get variable value from block?

Tags: ios, variables, block

Can i get variable value from block?

```
    - (Params *) getParams {
    __block Params* params = nil;
        //make post, get requests
    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:@"http://www.blankspot.ru/api/getinterval"
                                       params:nil
                                      completion:^(id json, JSONModelError *err) {
                                       NSLog(@"json = %@", json);
                                       NSLog(@"Error = %@", err );
                                      NSDictionary* json1 = json;
                                       NSLog(@" %@ ob ", [json1 objectForKey:@"success"]);
                                       params = [[Params alloc] initWithDictionary:json1 error:&err];

                                    NSLog(@"params123 = %@", params); // is not null
                                        }];

    NSLog(@"params123 = %@", params); //this is null
    return params;
   }
```

In first variant NSLog view non null value, but second variant after block will be nil.

Comment: you have to update this getJSONFromURLWithString: method. is this third party libary or you write it?

Comment: third party - JSONModel library for iOS

Comment: then you have to do a littl trick on this

Comment: thanks, i am handle exceptions in blocks and put need values to UserDefaltSettings or singleton class like Data Storage , from this blocks.

Comment: other way i am write a code for handeling this

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `getJSONFromURLWithString` is asynchronous (It uses `dispatch_async` to make the request call) which means it will be called on another thread while the current thread will keep running.

Your `NSLog` shows `nil` since the block is probably executed some time after the `NSLog` line is reached due to the asynchronous nature of the call (as URL requests take some time to complete and are not immediate)

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is to not use a return-statement, but making your own block where the value is returned. Like this:

in .h:

```
-(void)getParamsSuccess:(void(^)(Params* params))success;
```

in .m:

```
-(void)getParamsSuccess:(void(^)(Params *))success; {
    //make post, get requests
[JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:@"http://www.blankspot.ru/api/getinterval"
                                   params:nil
                                  completion:^(id json, JSONModelError *err) {
                                   NSLog(@"json = %@", json);
                                   NSLog(@"Error = %@", err );
                                  NSDictionary* json1 = json;
                                   NSLog(@" %@ ob ", [json1 objectForKey:@"success"]);
                                   Params* params = [[Params alloc] initWithDictionary:json1 error:&err];

                                NSLog(@"params123 = %@", params); // is not null


                                   success(params); // <-- This will call the handler-block with your params-object as the parameter


                                    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your completion block is executed asynchronously after some other action (e.g. network request) will be complete  (argument name "completion" should have given you a clue).
It means that lines

```
NSLog(@"params123 = %@", params); //this is null
return params;
```

will be executed way before your block. And at that point `params` will **still** be nil.

If you need to process received data, you should do it inside your completion block.
On the other hand, if you need to pass received parameters further, you'll have to create your own completion block parameter, because you get your result (Param *) after other operations are complete and not instantly.

Spoek suggested a good example, but don't forget to check `success` parameter for not being nil, otherwise when you'll try to call it, your app will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Used this:

```
-(void)getParams:(void(^)(Params *))finishBlock{
    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:@"http://www.blankspot.ru/api/getinterval"
                                      params:nil
                                  completion:^(id json, JSONModelError *err) {
                                      NSLog(@"json = %@", json);
                                      NSLog(@"Error = %@", err );
                                      NSDictionary* json1 = json;
                                      NSLog(@" %@ ob ", [json1 objectForKey:@"success"]);
                                      params = [[Params alloc] initWithDictionary:json1 error:&err];
                                      finishBlock(params);
                                      NSLog(@"params123 = %@", params); // is not null
                                  }];
}
```